# Write PL/SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, procedure, cursors

Write PL/SQL Procedure for the given Specification.
Assume the Table design is as follows :

```
Table Name : 
employee_details

Column Name Data Type   Constraint  
Emp_ID  NUMBER(5)   NOT NULL    Primary Key
Emp_Name    VARCHAR2(100)   NOT NULL    
Date_Joined DATE    NOT NULL    
Gender  CHAR(1) NOT NULL    
Salary  NUMBER(20,2)    NOT NULL    
Increment   CHAR(1) NULL    Y / N
```

Procedure is for incrementing the salary with the given value if the Increment Flag for the Employee is set to Y and commit the changes done

Procedure Name   :    PRC_INCREMENT
Input Parameters  :   a_Emp_ID,  a_Salary
Output Parameters : a_Exec_Status

return messages by procedure
if Given employee is not found  'EMPLOYEE IS NOT FOUND'
Employee is found and Increment flag is not Y   'INCREMENT NOT APPLICABLE FOR EMPLOYEE' – [GIVEN EMPLOYEE ID]
Successfully update 'SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED FOR EMPLOYEE' – [GIVEN EMPLOYEE ID]
Any other unhandled exception   ERROR  with the information about ORACLE ERROR

below code i have tried, plx help me with procedure

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Prc_increment(a_emp_id IN VARCHAR2, 
                                          a_salary IN VARCHAR2) 
AS 
  CURSOR c1 IS 
    SELECT emp_id, 
           salary, 
           increment_stat 
    FROM   emp 
    WHERE  emp_id = a_emp_id; 
  num_salary         emp.salary%TYPE; 
  num_emp_id         emp.emp_id%TYPE; 
  num_increment_stat emp.increment_stat%TYPE; 
BEGIN 
    OPEN c1; 

    LOOP 
        FETCH c1 INTO num_emp_id, num_salary, num_increment_stat; 

        IF num_emp_id <> a_emp_id THEN 
          dbms_output.Put_line('Employee not found'); 
        ELSIF num_increment_stat <> 'Y' THEN 
          dbms_output.Put_line('Employee not      eligible for increment'); 
        ELSE 
          UPDATE emp 
          SET    salary = num_salary + a_salary 
          WHERE  emp_id = a_emp_id 
                 AND increment_stat = 'Y'; 
        END IF; 

        EXIT WHEN c1% NOTFOUND; 
    END LOOP; 
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
             dbms_output.Put_line(SQLERRM); 

             CLOSE c1; 
END;
```

Comment: please describe the problem(s) you're experiencing with your current code. Then we don't have to spend time guessing or trying to figure it out. Tell us what you already know.

Comment: When am trying to execute the procedure with num_emp_id<>a_emp_id , dbms_output statement not getting executed, thats the problem in my code @ADyson